# the moire pattern - how to calibrate my LCD?

Tags: linux, xorg, monitors, intel-graphics, i915

I faced a strange issue (something like described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moir%C3%A9_pattern) and [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=kIviL42c28c#)); I am not sure but when I look at the lcd screen it feels like an eyes strain or similar which is quite uncomfortable; *On Linux Arch forums I could hear people describe they suffer eyes strain quite often using Arch OS so the problem is not unique*... Seems like the graphics is too sharp for look but still I am not sure cause the visual analysis gives no answer; **Moreover, I couldn't find what tools in linux should be used to fix/reduce that effect**?

So my question is :

- how to find out what is really wrong with graphics param-s and what values needed *(hsync,vsynch,brightness,contrast,color(rgb) etc)*?
- how to fix them if there are some graphics param-s settings errors?
- what apps (preferrably open source) shoud I use to calibrate?

**EDIT :**

The currrent screen resolution is 1366x768

```
$xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1366 x 768, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP1 connected 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
   1366x768      60.02*+
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   640x480       59.94  
...
```

Concerning image *(the photo)* it is the lines which are perfectly shown in this [questions images](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/130679/why-do-lcd-screens-ripple-through-cameras?newreg=3f4ec8be97b94d8db75dd02fa72038ca);

[image]

I understand it should be visible with camera only but in my case it seems to be a bit feel-like due to light shaking (flashing or similar) so it is quite tiring for eyes; So I do need to find out a way to reduce the effect; Moreover, I am not sure that it is not only reason causes eyes strain... maybe there are some color problems (rgb levels etc);

So I do need your advise of how to analyse what exactly causes graphics issue(s)?

Thanks

p.s.

- OS Linux Arch x64
- module : i915 (Intel HD Graphics)
- kernel-3.16.7

Comment: I don't believe arch has anything to do with it (it may not even be a software thing). On a digital carrier, the image should be pixel-by-pixel exact in sharpness, and maybe color-adjusted (gamma, color balance...). Maybe a sharpness filter, but it's uncommon as default. A lot of blame can always be put on the screen itself (and its transforms). If you connection is VGA, then you will of course get all the analog artifacts (moire, distortion, shift, noise, flicker,...). Again, all just hardware. However, you should clarify what exactly bothers you and what DE+effects are you using.

Comment: I have eDP port connected; This is notebook... I understand maybe I do need to do some calibration but on linux I don't know how to find out a) what needs to be calibrated b) how to calibrate the problem area(s)? So, yes, I think some additional settings needed but which ones I do need some helpful advice about that

Comment: Take a screenshot and watch it on a different computer/monitor. If it looks the same, then it has nothing to do with your screen (and your graphical interface just looks like that). If it's different, then you should try hardware configuration (buttons on the screen)... if that doesn't work, then tell us what xrandr outputs and what screen you have - maybe you are not running at native resolution an it is scaling the image! Also tell us what desktop environment you are using.

Comment: I tried watching screenshot on same screen resolution notebook with win xp pro installed; So the screenshot looks more I don't know stable or something; Maybe, yes, you right concerning the DPI and native resolution problem but I don't know how to check that :*| And is there a way to find out does the i915 is malfunctioned or something?

Comment: As I can see some kind of "LED light micro shaking" I can see that by watching my notebook build-in web cam run indicator right at the top-center of the lid; ... is there a way to check power unit? I mean how to know is it working correctly? I am asking cause I for some reason couldn't init the asus-laptop module cause of some error "modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'asus_laptop': No such device" so right now the notebook is working on the default ACPIs  only :(

Comment: At least post an image/screenshot/xrandr output/screen resolution, it's hard to debug without information.

Comment: @orion I edited my question watch it please

Comment: Moiré can be formed due to mismatch between pixel clocks of the video adapter and monitor. It can be changed with `xvidtune` on the computer side and from monitor’s own menu on the LCD side. Try to apply some small changes at luck; if moiré will move, then you are on a right track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to add that I have the effect decreased right after I have kernel which supports my processor series (BayTrail); So probably the effect is really depends on kernel version; p.s. the linux kernel version which started supporting Bay Trail is 4.0;

Before that I had kernel 3.16.7 which has the mentioned problems;

So in my case correct linux version solved the moire issue itself;

Comment: This doesn't answer any of the questions in the original post. Admittedly two of them were just statements with a question mark, but none of the questions in the bullet items of the original post are addressed by this answer.

Comment: @Anthon No, it answers the question; See kernel version I mention in the original question text; the kernel 3.16.7 has no bay trail support; My notebook has build-in graphics so processor and video card interaction takes place; So the answer is there is nothing to do with configurations or calibration (in my case of course) but correct linux version which supports main devices (preferably processor and video card);